# How to jump from one activity to another and set a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent, fragment

What i want is when i jump from one activity to another with intent it should also automatically set a fragment inside framelayout but i can't figure out how to do that any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question correctly, this code should help you:

In your first activity put this code:

```
public static final String FRAGMENTA = "FragmentA";
public static final String FRAGMENTB = "FragmentB";
public static final String FRAGMENTC = "FragmentB";

String fragmentToDisplay = FRAGMENTA;
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("fragmentToDisplay", fragmentToDisplay);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in your second activity in `onCreate`, receive the intent and set a fragment according to the string intent:

```
String fragmentToDisplay = getIntent.getStringExtra("fragmentToDisplay");
switch (fragmentToDisplay) {
    case FirstActivity.FRAGMENTA:
        //FragmentTransaction to show Fragment A
        break;
    case FirstActivity.FRAGMENTB:
        //FragmentTransaction to show Fragment B
        break;
    case FirstActivity.FRAGMENTC:
        //FragmentTransaction to show Fragment C
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your `firstActivity`, call the second intent to move to the next activity like this:

```
Intent intent= new Intent(firstActivity.this, secondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in your secondActivity, you can place a fragment by default like this:

```
// Put this code in your onCreate() method of secondActivity.
if(savedInstanceState == null) {
    Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.frame, fragment);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

The above code automatically get executed when `secondActivity` is launched, placing the `fragment` in `frame`.

Hope this helps :)